# 500 internal server error running php file in cgi-bin

Tags: httpd

500 internal server error is shown when

i access http://mysite.com/cgi-bin/test.php

test.php

```
<p> title here</p>
<?php 

echo "hi";

?>
```

error log shows

```
(8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/test.php' failed'. 
Premature end of script headers: test.php.
```

solved it by adding

```
            AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: So, is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Hey VVVVVV.  Clear up the confusion by Answering and Accepting your answer below in the Answer section.  Otherwise I'm with MGraff... what's the question?

Comment: php is not cgi(unless you are using the php cgi for some reason, which you are not).  You shouldn't be putting .php files in cgi-bin.

Answer (score 2):

You need the AddHandler statement, otherwise the script is executed as CGI, rather than PHP.